# Can RDP but not VNC a computer

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I'm having problem with one computer on our network.  I can RDP to it but not VNC.  Windows Firewall is turned off.  I tried uninstalling the version of VNC we were using and installing TightVNC but same results.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you doing this internally or from the outside. RDP communicates on 3389 where as VNC communicates on 5900.

Comment: Avoid using VNC. It is a remote assistance software, not a remote desktop software. It does not provide an adequate level of security.

Answer (score 0):

As kobaltz has said they use different ports although this is okay for your os seeing you have turned off windows firewall you will also need to open the incoming port on your router. each router has different way of doing this different, but the most commend are under Firewall setting are NAT forwarding or port forwarding. Check your router manual for these key words are the instructions on how to open a incoming port for your router should be there